# AD DNS update attempts from public IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, split-dns

Is there a way to only have DNS registration occur on truly internal networks? Maybe by leveraging the detection that windows firewall uses for domain interfaces?

As it sits we are regularly having laptops try registering `myworkstation.mydomain.com` to the public DNS service for whatever remote site they happen to be. This ends up creating a bunch of 8015 dns-client events and similar.

This fails of since we don't allow changes from public sources.  Usually I'd correct this by using `ad.mydomain.com` and having it not resolve publically, but for historical reason this split setup can't be removed.

Comment: Do you mean laptops on the public Internet try to register with your public DNS server?